# Recording 60fps on iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I have an iPhone5s and I was wondering how to shoot 60fps videos since it can shoot at 120fps
**I want a reliable and a free solution please**
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps softwarerecs.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2):

The stock camera app does not allow iPhone 5 to shoot in 60fps, however there are both jailbreak tweaks and App Store apps that allow you to do so. The tweak I know is named [CameraTweak](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/org.thebigboss.cameratweak3/) (seems to be iOS 8 and below though). There is also an app named [SlowPro](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/slopro-1000fps-slow-motion/id507232505?mt=8) that works just fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the iOS app [60fps Camera](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/60fps-camera/id714882169?mt=8) will enable you to shoot 60fps on an iPhone 5s. I've not tried it, however reviews seem to be better than average and it cost US$2.99.

By the way, I googled *iphone 5 app 60fps video* and it was the 2nd link. You might find other options this way as well.

Comment: I want a free solution if possible. I thought maybe there's a tweak to enable it on the Camera app. Or maybe a free reliable application.

Comment: You should update your question to reflect free and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this used to be possible under either iOS 5 or 6 on my iPHONE4. What you can do now is use another app which increases quality of the video/photo due to compression features which of course is still under the app's control and not iOS.